# Strange delays in ThreadStart_Context in .NET causing performance issues

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dottrace

I've written a relatively simple console utility that accesses the ClosedXML library, in order to produce an Excel spreadsheet. Nothing mind-blowing, and it should run really fast. However, when I launch it, it sits on the console screen for ~8s before displaying any progress.

At first, I thought this was the ClosedXML library taking a while to initialise. I fired up dotTrace and ran through it with line-by-line performance analysis, and got some strange results:

- Main Thread [14,352ms]

  - Main [99.29% - 14,251ms]

    - Generate [88.88% - 12,756ms]

      - 11 listed calls that add up to 23.44% / 4,360ms
    - get_Instance [6.78% - 974ms]
    - Console.ReadLine [2.75% - 394ms]
    - ResolvePolicy [0.82% - 118ms]
    - 11 hidden functions [0.01% - 1ms]
  - ResolvePolicy [0.20% - 29ms]
  - 7 listed calls that add up to 0.51% / 72ms
- Thread ".NET SystemEvents" [3,074ms]

  - ThreadStart [100% - 3,074ms]

    - Run [99.6% - 3,072ms]

      - ThreadStart_Context [99.93% - 3,072ms]

Now, if we dig into `ThreadStart_Context`, we see the following:

- System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object) [99.93% - 3,072ms]

  - Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowThreadProc [99.90% - 3,071ms]

    - Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx [87.26% - 2,682ms]

The `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` API is called a total of 26 times, according to the profiler. This means it's waiting around 100ms per wait.

The `Generate` method is something I wrote, and it talks to the ClosedXML library a lot. Part of the operation involves writing to disk, but that's done at the end, after console output should appear. The delay occurs before any work is done.

My concerns are twofold:

1. Why is there a 8,396ms time discrepancy in the results under the `Generate` call on the main thread?
2. Why are there so many calls to `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`, taking a total of 3 seconds? I understand that this might be due to thread synchronisation, but there is only 1 thread in the application.

**Update:** Ok, so I figured out that the second thread is actually handling the message loop, so the 5 seconds spent there are just areas where there aren't any window messages to process. Still not sure where that 8 second discrepancy comes in, though.